# Firebase transactions via REST API

Tags: rest, firebase

I find transactions (https://www.firebase.com/docs/transactions.html) to be a cool way of handling concurrency, however it seems they can only be done from clients.

The way we use Firebase is mainly by writing data from our servers and observing them on clients. Is there a way to achieve optimistic concurrency model when writing data via REST API?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Martin, how you envision that working? Keep in mind that that transactions rely on the a back-and-forth discussion where the client keeps attempting to set the data, the server keeps replying with concurrent changes, and they eventually settle on a value or give up.

Comment: Hi Kato, sure, I'm trying to implement the exact same discussion server-side. I can get current state of an object within firebase via GET request and then change it via PUT, but is there a way for me to know whether that object has been modified meanwhile?

Comment: I don't think so; which is part of the trouble with trying transactions via REST. I suppose we could throw together a solution that simulates transactions easily enough. Let me put in an answer.

Comment: REST transactions are officially supported now.  Check my answer below for links to blog and docs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could utilize an update counter to make write ops work in a similar way to transactions. (I'm going to use some pseudo-code below; sorry for that but I didn't want to write out a full REST API for an example.)

For example, if I have an object like this:

```
{
   total: 100,
   update_counter: 0
}
```

And a write rule like this:

```
{
   ".write": "newData.hasChild('update_counter')",
   "update_counter": {
      ".validate": "newData.val() === data.val()+1"
   }
}
```

I could now prevent concurrent modifications by simply passing in the update_counter with each operation. For example:

```
var url = 'https://<INSTANCE>.firebaseio.com/path/to/data.json';
addToTotal(url, 25, function(data) {
   console.log('new total is '+data.total);
});

function addToTotal(url, amount, next) {
   getCurrentValue(url, function(in) {
      var data = { total: in.total+amount, update_counter: in.update_counter+1 };
      setCurrentValue(ref, data, next, addToTotal.bind(null, ref, amount, next));
   });
}

function getCurrentValue(url, next) {
   // var data = (results of GET request to the URL) 
   next( data );
}

function setCurrentValue(url, data, next, retryMethod) {
   // set the data with a PUT request to the URL
   // if the PUT fails with 403 (permission denied) then
   // we assume there was a concurrent edit and we need
   // to try our pseudo-transaction again
   // we have to make some assumptions that permission_denied does not
   // occur for any other reasons, so we might want some extra checking, fallbacks,
   // or a max number of retries here
   // var statusCode = (server's response code to PUT request)
   if( statusCode === 403 ) {
       retryMethod();
   }
   else {
       next(data);
   }
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty impresive, thanks a lot! I'll try to implement it and let you know if any troubles.

Comment: Works perfectly for updating objects. Is it possible to implement a similar thing for deleting?

Comment: @MartinŠťáva It isn't really possible to do that, I think, since you don't pass data with a DELETE. I don't think most systems care about this, because they assume if you say DELETE, you really mean DELETE, and don't care what was in there before that, as long as you're referencing the right key/URL.

Comment: I referenced this answer in a question on the python-firebase REST wrapper issue list - https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase/issues/20#issuecomment-71334643

Comment: I think a challenge of using Auth to do this is if you're using auth for other things, there isn't a way to distinguish why your validate failed. Was it due to a CAS abort/retry loop, or was it because you tried to add buggy data that really failed validation?

Comment: need to consider null case, the final .validate rule I use is "data.val() === null || newData.val() === data.val()+1"

Answer (score 5):

FYI, Firebase Realtime Database officially supports this now.

Read the [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/07/introducing-conditional-rest-requests.html) and the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-conditional-requests) for more info.

Comment: @Martin Šťáva Yes, they do and I am using it and it works.

Answer (score 3):

check out Firebase-Transactions project: https://github.com/vacuumlabs/firebase-transactions

I believe, this may be quite handy for your case, especially if you do a lot of writes from the server.

(disclaimer: I'm one of the authors)